# Oracle - calculate number of rows before some condition is applied

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how many rows would be returned without rownum condition in a given query:

```
SELECT columns
, [number of rows before applying rownum] AS numberofrows
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
AND rownum < 100
```

Is it possible without using a subquery?

Comment: it depends to your tool, in sql*plus, its returns till end, In sql developer, it only display and return 1st 50 rows, and updating on viewing the remaining part. Or you need to use `count(*)` function

Comment: Your title refers to 'some condition' being applied; are you only talking about limiting on `rownum` as the question text suggests? It's a little ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexPoole No, there is a bunch of conditions which are to be applied. I want to know the record count after they are applied, but before rownum - I was curious if there was some hack to do it without subquery.

Comment: @kyooryu - OK, that was how I read it first; then I think my answer does what you want. All the conditions except the `rownum` one go in the inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytic version of `COUNT()` in a nested query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT table_name,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS numberofrows
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE owner = 'SYS'
  ORDER BY table_name
)
WHERE rownum < 10;
```

You need to nest it anyway to apply an order-by before the `rownum` filter to get consistent results, otherwise you get a random(ish) set of rows.

You can also replace `rownum` with the analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT table_name, cnt FROM
(
  SELECT table_name,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS numberofrows,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table_name) AS rn
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE owner = 'SYS'
)
WHERE rn < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two queries. First to find the size of set and second with data.

`select count(*) from tables where conditions;`

then the second one.

Note that before you should order your set to have, and wrap it to another select

`select * from (select columns from tables where conditions order by columns) rownum < 100`.

[Lecture about limiting resources](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use conditional aggregation:

```
      select sum(case when conditions then 1 else 0 end) as NumWithConditions,
             count(*) as Total
      from tables;
```